# rails--delayed_job : how do I put my code into background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

```
gem 'daemon-spawn'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

I have a class "DoingJob" which has a method "perform".

```
def perform
  loop do 
     // my code in infinity loop
  end
```

In my controller "Simple", I create a DoingJob instance "job" and call Job.delay.perform. Nothing happens and no error apears on web page.

```
class SimpleController < ApplicationController
require 'opening_job.rb'
    def welcome
      job = OpeningJob.new
      job.delay.perform     
    end
end
```

I also performed an experiment  on rails console.

```
user:~/workspace/blog (master) $ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
2.2.1 :001 > require 'job.rb'
 => true 
2.2.1 :002 > ob =  OpeningJob.new
 => #<OpeningJob:0x000000037ff0f0> 
2.2.1 :003 > ob.delay.perform
```

it appears

```
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("handler", "run_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["handler", "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject: !ruby/object:OpeningJob {}\nmethod_name: :perform\nargs: []\n"], ["run_at", "2015-11-26 09:24:27.724717"], ["created_at", "2015-11-26 09:24:27.726736"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-26 09:24:27.726736"]]
   (21.0ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 3, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2015-11-26 09:24:27", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, queue: nil, created_at: "2015-11-26 09:24:27", updated_at: "2015-11-26 09:24:27"> 
2.2.1 :004 > Delayed::Job.last
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs"  ORDER BY "delayed_jobs"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

So, the problem is that  No jobs are added in the database!

**But job can be added when I open rails console --sandbox.**

Comment: You can examine if job has been added into the queue with `Delayed::Job.last` from the rails console. Also do you have the delayed_job daemon started?

Comment: @Mareq  it produced nil.

Comment: @user60627 i think your delayed run successfully. you can check is your method is executed or not??.

Comment: @VishalJAIN  It doesn't since it does not read a remote json file and write to a file. If I don't use delayed_job, it is successfully so my code is correct.